# Asp.net Core 2.1 Pass AzureAd Authentication Bearer to Web Api which uses [Authorize]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that uses AzureAd registered app service for authentication.
Its purpose will be to act as a backend service to UI front ends.
I have tested security functionality using postman, headers, JWT Authorization, etc., and that works successfully.  
Now, I have created a front end in ASP.NET Core 2.1 as an MVC web app.
I have AzureAd login working on the front end.
As a test, I have tried an Ajax request to the backend Web API.
But, I get a 401 Unauthorized response because I do not know how to pass the Authorization Bearer in the request headers, I presume this is my problem.

My question is how is this done?
How do I authenticate to an ASP.NET Core Web API from an ASP.NET Core Web app?
I would like to use a streamlined approach like this, if possible.
And/Or, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer to this problem after reading about middleware and HttpClient requests.
In case anyone finds their self in the same boat here is how I solved it.

1. Capture the azure "Bearer" token and store token server-side as an identity claim of the user.
2. Make a method to send http requests to the Web Api.

Like this as follows:

GETTING AND STORING THE TOKEN
This goes in your startup.cs where you configure servcies for AzureAd/OpenIdConnect.

```
builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
        builder.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
        {
            //Additional config snipped
            o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    if (identity != null)
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", context.SecurityToken.RawData));
                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(context.SecurityToken.RawData + "\n\n");
                }
            };
        });
```

METHOD FOR SENDING ALL HTTP REQUESTS WITH THE AUTHORIZATION TOKEN.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AjaxAction(string url)
    {
        if (User.Claims == null) return null;
        System.Security.Claims.Claim claim = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Type == "access_token");
        if (claim == null) return null;

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", claim.Value);
        string url_e = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        // Here we ask the framework to dispose the response object a the end of the user resquest
        HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(response);

        return new HttpResponseMessageResult(response);
    }
```